# Bug: zero visitors/day on Materials.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-stats

The site stats on the main [Materials.SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/) site shows 0 visitors/day, yet on Area 51 it is 319 visitors/day.

[image: zero visitors/day]

Could this bug be resolved?

Comment: @Camps this question was correctly tagged as non-reproducible by Catija. status-completed is for problems that the development team did work on.

Comment: @NikeDattani thanks. Should I change it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it says 318 visits/day:

[image]

This is interesting. I wonder if it would be fixed if you cleared your cookies or switched from Chrome to Firefox (or from browser A to browser B)?

Comment: Hm, it's updated now (I can also see 318). I've flagged the question to add the [status-completed] tag.

Comment: I don't know how often the Community Team looks at the flags, maybe if you remove the "bug" tag it would be enough?

Comment: Our three pro-tempore mods will be elected next week, perhaps then the post can be tagged with status completed